# Mount usb drive in SnapdragonAPQ8074 using mount command

Tags: android, linux, mount, usb-otg

I logged with root and connected usb3.0 to usb3.0 port of snapdragon board ,it is detected when i checked the logs:

```
    <6>[   45.926428] usb 3-1.4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
    <6>[   45.947336] usb 3-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581

     <6>[   45.947343] usb 3-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1,  Product=2,   SerialNumber=3
     <6>[   45.947349] usb 3-1.4: Product: Ultra
     <6>[   45.947354] usb 3-1.4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
     <6>[   45.947360] usb 3-1.4: SerialNumber: 4C530123230927123460
     <6>[   45.949158] scsi0 : usb-storage 3-1.4:1.0
     <5>[   46.946864] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
     <5>[   46.956938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
      <5>[   46.957685] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
      <5>[   46.969755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
      <7>[   46.973533] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
      <5>[   46.973914] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, readcache: enabled,doesn't support DPO or FUA
      <6>[   47.004965]  sda: sda1
      <5>[   47.008665] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

and tried to mount it with the following command:

```
  mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/sdcard/
```

it is showing an Error: 'Mount:No such device'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android, the device node may be `/dev/block/sda1` instead of `/dev/sda1`

Comment: I tried with BLOCK but it is not working it is showing still Error: `[  231.883428] mount: sending ioctl 125d to a partition!
[  231.887613] mount: sending ioctl 125d to a partition!
mount: No such device`